# Print a rectangular in java

Tags: java, rectangles

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter width: ");
    int w = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter height: ");
    int h = input.nextInt();

    printHeight("x", h);
    printWidth("x", w);

}

private static void printHeight(String height, int count) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        System.out.println(height);
    }
}

private static void printWidth(String width, int count1) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= count1; j++) {
        System.out.print(width);
    }
}
```

I am trying to print a rectangle with input height and width, but they show a different pattern. Is there any way to nest them?

Comment: What should the output look like if I (for example) entered `2` and `3` as the input?

Comment: 1 line print xxx as width and 2 rows with xxx and xxx so total 6x.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a rectangle in the console using the following code:

```
package test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printRect(5,10,'x');
    }

    private static void printRect(int width,int height,char marker) {
        printHorizontal(width,marker);
        for(int j=0;j<height-2;j++) {
            printVertical(width,marker);
        }
        printHorizontal(width,marker);
    }

    private static void printVertical(int width, char marker) {
        System.out.print(marker);
        for (int j = 0; j < width-2; j++) {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println(marker);
    }

    private static void printHorizontal(int width,char marker) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width-1; j++) {
            System.out.print(marker);
        }
        System.out.println(marker);
    }

}
```

output:

```
xxxxx
x   x
x   x
x   x
x   x
x   x
x   x
x   x
x   x
xxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter width: ");
        int w = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter height: ");
        int h = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("A filled rectangle:");
        printFilledRectangle("x", w, h);
        System.out.println("An empty rectangle:");
        printEmptyRectangle("x", w, h);
    }

    private static void printFilledRectangle(String character, int width, int height) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
                System.out.print(character);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void printEmptyRectangle(String character, int width, int height) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
            System.out.print(character);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 1; i <= height - 2; i++) {
            System.out.print(character);
            for (int j = 1; j <= width - 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(character);
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
            System.out.print(character);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter width: 10
Enter height: 8
A filled rectangle:
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
An empty rectangle:
xxxxxxxxxx
x        x
x        x
x        x
x        x
x        x
x        x
xxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodsSecond {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter width: ");
        int w = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter height: ");
        int h = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        printRectangle("x" , w, h);
    }

    private static void printRectangle(String character, int width, int height) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
                System.out.print(character);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you guys a lot. I just didnt understand nest loop. Would you mind share some thoughts about books for further studying? We dont have a lot of lectures in class and we only have quick pdf introduction material.